# ¿Como puedo crear base de datos cada año y seleccionar el año que deseo por un select y se despleguen los registros de ese año?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

¡Hola ! Resulta que necesito crear bases de datos cada año de forma incremental y automatica con sus campos y tablas correspondientes, ya que , necesito que cada base de datos pueda almacenar informacion referente al tipo de año , por ejemplo : db2021, db2022,db2023 asi sucesivamente , y que los registros que fueron hechos en el año 2021 sean del año 2021 , registros me refiero a los registros de la tabla de base de datos , el tipico registro , y que por ejemplo con un select , pueda seleccionar el año que desee y se desplegen los registros de ese año , y claramente al ser una nueva base de datos los id de cada tabla empiezan nuevamente en 1 ya que no hay registros , tal vez no lo explique muy claro, pero en los comentarios si tienen dudas , hare todo lo posible por contestar!De antemano Muchas Gracias! Me ayudarian muchisimo!

Comment: Y no te resultaría más sencillo incluir en cada tabla un campo que indique el año? Lo digo porque a la hora de manejar las diferentes conexiones con la base de datos te vas a complicar la vida. Es más sencillo y práctico indicar en cada registro el año al que pertenece, así si te piden que visualices datos de diferentes años no tendrás tanta complicación

Comment: @ÓscarNovás Gracias por responder Oscar! Y estoy absolutamente de acuerdo contigo , es más asi lo tengo , puedo buscar y filtrar por año , y tengo en cada registro su fecha de registro , pero resulta que me estan pidiendo que en cada año las tablas se "reseteen" por asi decirlo y que el id comienze nuevamente a 1 y que la informacion no se pierda más poder observar sus registros de ese año, es enredoso pero bueno es lo que me pidieron.

Comment: Te vas a enredar la vida, pero es posible hacerlo. Podrías crear un archivo php que se ejecute cada determinada fecha (con un CRON), y con un condicional valide la fecha y si la DB existe. (además si tienes permisos para crear la base de datos). En caso que todo se cumpla, bastaría con una sentencia CREATE DATABASE.

Comment: Y es solo para una tabla o para muchas? porque también podrías tener una sola tabla que se llame por ejemplo "registros" (que sería la del año actual, en este caso 2022)... y con un cron a final de año, renombras esa tabla a "registros2020", y luego creas otra vez la tabla "registros" (que aplicaría para el transcurso del 2023) y así sucesivamente... no sé, es una idea... ya si son muchas tablas relacionadas depronto ya no quede tan facil de hacer...

Comment: Si son muchas tablas siempre puedes exportar el sql de creación de tablas, y con un script (bash, php o lo que quieras) que se ejecute vía crontab crear la base de datos e importar la estructura "limpia"

Comment: @ÓscarNovás Claro!, lo que indicas crees que es dificil de implementar o hay algun tipo de libreria que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: @JheymanMejia Gracias por la idea ! , habia visto un programa de sistema de gestion que veia que se producia el fitrlo por año y al seleccionar ese año me muestra los registros de aquel año , no sabia que era tal vez medio enredoso implementarlo,crees que una libreria u algo podria ayudarme a facilitar esa funcionalidad?

Comment: Fácil o difícil siempre depende de los conocimientos de cada uno. Yo haría un script bash dónde primero comprobaría si existe la base de datos de mysql y si no existe que la cree (mirate comandos de mysql en consola). Una vez creada lanzaría el comando de mysql para importar el archivo con las sentencias de creación de tablas. Una vez tienes el script puedes añadirlo al crontab del servidor para que se ejecute cada 1 de enero por ejemplo.

Comment: @Pipe Son como 6 0 7 tablas , mas o menos tendria que ser si o si con un cron?

Comment: @ÓscarNovás Y tiene que ser si o si con cronjob? trabajo en un cpanel para subirlo en un hosting y hay un apartado de cron tendria que producirlo ahi? De antemano Muchas Gracias!

Comment: El CRON es como las tareas programadas de Windows, sólo hace eso: Ejecuta un archivo cada X tiempo. Las instrucciones dependen del contenido de dicho archivo y del lenguaje que quieras usar, yo personalmente lo haría con PHP, ya que te permite guardar las credenciales para que tu cPanel cree las bases de datos. También ten en cuenta que si es un hosting compartido, a lo mejor tengas un límite de bases de datos, y adicional, si vas a ejecutar la instrucción en otro lenguaje, prueba que el cPanel sea compatible con ese lenguaje.

Comment: @Pipe Y en esa tabla de registros producirle los campos id_registro y año_registro? y como dices tu que se cree de forma incremental ? y relacionarla con las otras tablas?

Comment: Por eso dije... si solo es una tabla sería viable... si esta está relacionada con muchas otras o muchas otras relacionadas con esta... ahi la cosa se complica bastante